# How update the chart type of ApexCharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, apexcharts

I need to update the chart type of an already rendered ApexCharts.

From what I looked at the [methods](https://apexcharts.com/docs/methods/), I tried using the `updateOptions()` method, but returned the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelectorAll' of undefined`.

I have another question too ... Can I update the chart without informing the data again?

**Code:**
https://jsfiddle.net/leorcdias/yzwx6qh4/4/

My idea is to update the chart without having to put the data all over again ...

I really hope someone can help me! Thanks..

Answer (score 3):

I tried to use `updateOptions({type: 'selectedType'})`, but it caused no result.

However, `updateSeries()` method save my life :) I use it *only for* changing type of a chart. For changing every other options I use `updateOptions`.

In total I have the following code:

```
chart.updateSeries([{type: 'MyType'}]); 
chart.updateOptions({every: other, options: you, want: toChange}});
```

**EDIT**

I'm sorry, but all my **text above** has **no sense**!

So, you have 2 questions.

1. `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelectorAll' of undefined`

You can call `updateOptions` method (like another API methods) only on the ApexCharts instances which have to be created only one time. In your case such instance is var *chart*. But there are problems: 1) you are trying to create it multiple times (before initial render and before updating), 2) this instance is in the local scope every time!

2)

> Can I update the chart without informing the data again?

The *data* is the *series* array. The series structure depends on chart type.
In case of pie it's just an array of number values. In cases of bar, line, area it's an array of objects. See Docs/Chart Types and Docs/Demos. So, if you want to change a chart type to another with a different series structure, convert your series structure before! In another cases updating is realy easy, just example:

```
chart.updateOptions({legend:{show:false}, stroke: {width:8}});
```

I have re-written your code with minimum, **check it**: https://jsfiddle.net/kvipe/7sxLrz54/7/, happy to help!

Comment: @vsync you are absolutely right! I mean `updateOptions` method of course. Fixed it.